# How to select button WITHIN some divs but NOT other divs?

Tags: html, class, text, imacros

The HTML I have to select from:

```
<div class="diviWANT">
<div class="adiv">
</div>
<button class="abutton" type="button">
    <span class="aspan">
        <i class="ani"></i> 
            SomeText
    </span>
    <span class="aclass2">
        SomeText2
    </span>
    <span class="aclass3">
        SomeText3
    </span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="diviDONOTwant">
    <div class="adiv">
    </div>
    <button class="abutton" type="button">
        <span class="aspan">
            <i class="ani"></i> 
                SomeText
        </span>
        <span class="aclass2">
            SomeText2
        </span>
        <span class="aclass3">
            SomeText3
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Please note that the two divs are IDENTICAL except for the following:
`<div class="diviWANT">` and `<div class="diviDONOTwant">`.

---

The following is my NONWORKING imacros script (NO BUTTON IS SELECTED AT ALL)

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:diviWANT&&TXT:SomeText
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:diviWANT&&TXT:SomeText
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:diviWANT&&TXT:SomeText
```

Ans here is my former NONWORKING imacros script (selects ALL BUTTONS EVEN THE ONES I DO NOT WANT)

```
VERSION BUILD=6060703 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:aspan&&TXT:SomeText
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:aspan&&TXT:SomeText
TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:aspan&&TXT:SomeText
```

So how can I make it work?

---

---

---

Here is a jsbin for you to test to try to get it to work (updated to new one):
http://jsbin.com/AnewiNE/1/
If the button is clicked it turns purple. (this is for your reference so you know if it clicked the button or not.)
The only buttons that should be selected are the ones inside the divs with class `diviWANT`. These are random, there is no method or rhythm to the placement of `diviWANT` divs. i.e. you can't just select odd numbers, etc. You need to seek out and find only the buttons within `diviWANT` divs based only on the given html in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i=1;
  do
   {
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:SomeText* EXTRACT=HTM");
    if(iimGetLastExtract()!='#EANF#')
       {
        if(iimGetLastExtract().indexOf("diviWANT")>0)
           {
            iimSet("i", i);
            iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:SomeText*");
           }
       }
        else break;  
    i++;
   }
   while(i);
```

Tested on http://jsbin.com/oPuFiHa/4 and http://jsbin.com/AnewiNE/1 - it's working.

Note: replace `indexOf("diviWANT")` with `indexOf("REAL_DIV_CLASS_NAME")`

This is a JS code, save it in iMacros folder with extension *.js, not *.iim. Then refresh the iMacros list, more about JS read [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface).

P.S.: My final attempt to help you, based on details you provided, good luck.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for only putting the div, but it just outlines the div but does not click the button inside.

Comment: You didn't explain exactly what you want.
From the start you should said that you want to click a button which is in a DIV element.
Give us a real page where we could test it

Comment: it seems that you have only 2 buttons, right?

look here - http://jsbin.com/AYAJIfI/1

Comment: TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:b1
TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:b1
TAG POS=3 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:b1

etc. ))

Comment: sorry, but the real code doesn't have b1. i should update the jsbin so it doesn't have b1.

Comment: you should specify the real names of classes, ids, or whatever, and how exactly these elements are sorted in BODY element, otherwise it's a waste of time

Comment: see edited answer, it is working on that jsbin, but i don't think it will work on your real page

Comment: You can't just skip even numbers. Let me update the jsbin yet again to remove that possibility because the real page doesn't have every other, they are random. OK here is the new jsbin that eliminated the confusion with b1 and b2 and also the possibility of only choosing even or odd numbers which is not possible since they are randomly one or the other. http://jsbin.com/AnewiNE/1/

Comment: well even though you haven't given a working solution yet, it is helpful to know that I can use javascript. I think that iMacros scripts perhaps it is impossible; but perhaps a javascript script will allow it. Waiting for your new answer.

Comment: Perhaps we could create a javascript `if` it's located in `diviWANT` div, then use the code and `else` statement then don't click?

Comment: ok actually looks like you've given up. I will wait for another answerer.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I had to use Firefox though because Chrome iMacros won't accept js files. Wonderful work. Thank you very much. Accepted as best answer.

Comment: p.s. your skill way supersedes mine; I could not have written this, I don't have the knowledge. Thanks again. Now I need to make it wait 0.2 seconds in between each click, I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: great, it was easy to add new functions like to wait 1 second between each click by just adding new lines after `iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");`, by wrapping each new line with `iimPlay("CODE:");` like I added this line after it to wait 1 second between each click: `iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=1");`

Answer (score 1):

To select something within something else try this example

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:JUST_AN_EXAMPLE&&TXT:SomeText
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:aOTHERspan&&TXT:SomeText
```

If this solves the problem let us know. Otherwise I will edit the answer. I can't tell from your code what div you want to select and what to leave.

Edited: The method is the same you just need to change it a little bit. So this will select a DIV and select SPAN in it. Since the DIV tag will be different then the other same SPAN in another DIV will not be selected.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point; I'm not selecting a span within a span. I'm selecting a span within SOME DIVs but not within other DIVs. What you put as an answer would only work if they are both within the SAME div. Not to mention I can't even try your example because you listed "aOTHERspan" which does not exist in my example.

Comment: Thanks! It works, I voted up! I would choose this as best answer, except that the other guy put so much work into the his working solution. I voted up.